# LP Constraint Problem

Tags: linear-programming

If you have an investment fund which has four options $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$

More should be invested in the combination of funds $x_2$ and $x_3$ than funds $x_1$ and $x_4$ by a ratio of at least $1.5:1$.

The constraint I have formed is as follows:

$$1.5(x_2 + x_3) - (x_1 + x_4) \geq 0.$$

Would this be the correct representation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it is the other way around. $(x_2+x_3)-1.5(x_1+x_4)\geq0$

Answer (score 0):

No it is not right. The inequality should be

$\frac{1}{1.5}(x_2 + x_3) - (x_1 + x_4) \geq 0$

This is equivalent to

$\frac{2}{3}(x_2 + x_3) - (x_1 + x_4) \geq 0$

If $x_1 + x_4= 100$  the inequality holds if $x_2 + x_3\geq 150$

But there are two additional readings.

**1)** In $x_2 + x_3$ has be at least 1.5 time more invested than in $x_1 + x_4$

This means that $x_2 + x_3$ has to be (at least) $2.5(=1+1.5)$ times of $x_1 + x_4$

$\frac{1}{2.5}(x_2 + x_3) - (x_1 + x_4) \geq 0$

This is equivalent to

$0.4(x_2 + x_3) - (x_1 + x_4) \geq 0$

If $x_1 + x_4= 100$  the inequality holds if $x_2 + x_3\geq 250$

**2.** Interpreting of "more"

**a)** 1.5 is more than 1. Therfore it could be an equality sign.

$$\frac{2}{3}(x_2 + x_3) - (x_1 + x_4) = 0$$ or

$$0.4(x_2 + x_3) - (x_1 + x_4) = 0$$

**b)** The ratio has to be more than 1.5

$$\frac{2}{3}(x_2 + x_3) - (x_1 + x_4) \geq 0$$ or

$$0.4(x_2 + x_3) - (x_1 + x_4) \geq 0$$

For me the condition is not well defined and I have the 4 possible variants above.